# After Clicking on the lightning cancel button it has to redirect to Home page in salesforce .How can we do it?

Tags: lightning-aura-components

javascript :

```
navigateUrl : function(component,event,helper) {



    var navService= component.find("navService");
    var pageReference =
        {    
            "type": "standard__namedPage",
            "attributes": {
                "pageName": "Home"    
            } 

        }; console.log('pageReference'+pageReference);  
    navService.navigate(pageReference);
}
```

component button :`<lightning:button variant="brand" label="Cancel" onclick="{!c.navigateUrl}"/>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead, You can use force:navigateToURL. It will navigate to you to the specified URL. In this case you will navigate to home page.

```
gotoURL : function (component, event, helper) {
    var urlEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToURL");
    urlEvent.setParams({
      "url": "/lightning/page/home"
    });
    urlEvent.fire();
}
```

Read more about it here:- [Navigate To Url](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation)

Comment: Thanks bro.Its working fine.